# Unauthorized to create AppInstaceUser with php sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

Im using Amazon Chime SDK messaging but Im having some troubles.

From the aws console, I have created and AppInstance and AppInstanceUser for testing. Then, with php sdk I have tried to createChannel and it was created. I have tried with createAppInstance, createAccount from php sdk and they were ok too, so I have permissions for access to api. In fact, Im trying with a key/secret with full permissions.

The problem is when I try to createAppInstaceUser.

```
public function createAppInstanceUser(User $user)
{
    $appUserInstanceUser = $this->chime->createAppInstanceUser(
        [
            'AppInstanceArn' => $this->appInstanceArn,
            'AppInstanceUserId' => $user->getId(),
            'ClientRequestToken' => uniqid(),
            'Name' => $user->getName()
        ]
    );

    return $appUserInstanceUser;
}
enter code here
```

Then:

> "Error executing "CreateAppInstanceUser" on
> "https://identity-chime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-instance-users";
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://identity-chime.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-instance-users`
> resulted in a `401 Unauthorized`
> response:{"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"User is not
> authorized","RequestId":null,"Resource":null}\n
> UnauthorizedClientException (client): User is not authorized -
> {"Code":"Unauthorized","Message":"User is not
> authorized","RequestId":null,"Resource":null}",

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

AppInstanceUserId must be string. I cannot explain why the chime api return an unauthorized when the problem is a var type :D